# JQuery only highlight prepended text

Tags: jquery

I need to highlight the text that I prepend; not the entire string. My code below highlights everything.

```
jQuery("#foo").prepend("<li>Addition li</li>").effect("highlight", {}, 1000)
```

So I only want to highlight that new

. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`prependTo()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo) and go the other way instead of [`prepend()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend#content):

```
$("<li>Addition li</li>").effect("highlight", {}, 1000).prependTo("#foo");
```

or you may want to prepend first:

```
$("<li>Addition li</li>").prependTo("#foo").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
```

Comment: Just to clarify why this works, it is because the `prepend()` function continues the chain with the original selection, not the recently prepended item. By using `prependTo`, the chain continues with the prepended item as the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the prepended text with a class and style it in your css? This may or not be suitable depending on your requirements, but i'd say its the simplest approach.